# java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException for UCS-2

Tags: java, exception, ucs2

I have some Hungarian text and I would like it to be encoded with UCS2 encoding

```
String stringEncoding = "UCS-2";
String contentHardCoded = new String("szigorúan bejelentkezési azonosításhoz".getBytes(),stringEncoding);
```

But I am getting the following exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException: UCS-2
    at java.lang.StringCoding.decode(StringCoding.java:170)
    at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:443)
    at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:515)
    at com.gtl.mindmatics.sms.Main.sendSMS(Main.java:108)
    at com.gtl.mindmatics.sms.Main.main(Main.java:180)
Java Result: 1
```

What could be wrong?

**EDIT**

I use the following command to run my jar
Actually my command is like

`java -Dfile.encoding=UCS-2 -cp MyApp.jar com.sms.Main "9876543210" “UCS-2” > testApp.log`

And also what should be the correct encoding that should be used, i used UTF-8 but the output not correct.

Comment: The canonical names of the encodings supported by Oracle's implementation of Java 8 are listed [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/intl/encoding.doc.html). As an aside, `getBytes()` must be given the same encoding or the operation is not symmetrical and the string will be corrupted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing it wrong; a `String` is a set of characters and that is all. What you do here is:

- you get the bytes of the string as decoded by your *current JVM encoding*,
- you reencode these bytes using a *different encoding*.

Your string will therefore be completely corrupted. A `String` *does not have an encoding*.

See [here](http://fgaliegue.blogspot.com/2014/03/strings-characters-bytes-and-character.html) for more details.

---

As to UCS-2, it has been superseded by UTF-16. You want to use UTF-16 instead.

Note that you MUST specify the endianness, which matters for UTF-16 unlike for UTF-8. Use:

```
StandardCharsets.UTF_16LE
```

(or `BE` for big endian), or, if you still use Java 6 or lower:

```
Charset.forName("UTF-16LE") // or BE
```

Comment: Sorry to I forgot to mention, my command is like : java -Dfile.encoding=UCS-2 -cp MyApp.jar com.sms.Main "9876543210" “UCS-2” > testApp.log, so i think i am resetting current JVM encoding.

Comment: Beware of using UTF-16 without specifying endianness! If no endianness is defined it is big endian by default.